# AmMap - keeping the same zoom level and position after updating map data

Tags: javascript, amcharts, ammap

I am updating the map areas of an AmMap map, but the zoom level and position is reset whenever I do.

My function which is updating the map is:

```
function setData(data) {
    var parsedData = JSON.parse(data);

    map.dataProvider.areas = parsedData.areas;
    map.validateData();
}
```

I have tried a bunch of things, but I can't get this to work.

Cheers for any help.

Answer (score 4):

before you update your data, get the current zoom values and pass them into the dataprovider. Take a look to following sample http://www.amcharts.com/tips/retaining-map-zoom-level-position-data-update/

Comment: the zoomLevel method doesn't seem to be working, I get a "Cannot read property 'scale' of undefined" error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [**Maertz**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25186774/ammap-keeping-the-same-zoom-level-and-position-after-updating-map-data/26702439#26702439) answer, remember to set `zoomLatitude` and `zoomLongitude` to zero so you won't get the "Cannot read property 'scale' of undefined" error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `var map = event.chart;` at the method start.